# python - how to authenticate against GmailAPI without user input

Tags: python, authentication, google-api, gmail-api, credentials

I have a small python script that collects some data and sends it in an email using the gmail api. My goal is to put this script on my raspberry, create a daily cronjob that calls it and forget about it. However, the way I have done my google authentication prevents me from automating it. Currently I have to authenticate using my browser(user needs to press the allow button), then I can use the credentials for a few days and then they expire and user input is required again. How can I make it authenticate once and then start refreshing its credentials automatically?

Current code:

```py
def get_creds():
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(dir,'token.json')):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)

    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            print("refreshing")
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                os.path.join(dir,'credentials.json'), SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

        with open(os.path.join(dir,'token.json'), 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    return creds
```

Comment: I recently answered something like this. The solution is to use a refresh token, which your code sample already has, but to prevent token expiration you need to publish the project or set it as internal. See [avoid auth token to expire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72406414/avoid-auth-token-to-expire)

Comment: You can only set project to to internal if you are a Google Workspace user. "Because you're not a Google Workspace user, you can only make your app available to external (general audience) users."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Daniel mentioned the problem was that my GoogleCLoud app was in test mode. I had to publish it first and then it started refreshing the token successfully without my help.

[avoid auth token to expire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72406414/avoid-auth-token-to-expire)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [service account](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7378726?hl=en) instead of token. It doesn't expire.

```py
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    CREDENTIALS_JSON_PATH,
    SCOPES
)

service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

print(service.users().getProfile(userId='me').execute())
```

If you create [Google Workspace service account](https://support.google.com/workspacemigrate/answer/9222993?hl=en) you need to specify user email address

```py
credentials = credentials.with_subject(USER_EMAIL)
```